# Error when inheriting from templated class and calling templated function

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

I've got some template code that I'm modifying and I've run into an odd error that I can't work around.  I was able to recreate the problem with the below simpler (but admittedly pointless) code snippet:

```
struct Widget
{
};

template <typename A>
class Foo
{
public:

    template <int numA>
    inline bool funcCall()
    {
        return numA > 0;
    }

    inline bool funcCallNoTemplate()
    {
        return false;
    }
};

template <typename B>
class Bar : public Foo<B>
{
public:

    // doesn't work
    bool concrete()
    {
        return Foo<B>::funcCall<5>();
    }

    // works fine
    bool other()
    {
        return Foo<B>::funcCallNoTemplate();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Bar<Widget> b;
    b.concrete();
    b.other();
    return 0;
}
```

The error I get with GCC 4.7 is the following (line 30 is the body of Bar::concrete):

```
example.cxx: In member function ‘bool Bar<B>::concrete()’:
example.cxx:30: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
example.cxx: In member function ‘bool Bar<B>::concrete() [with B = Widget]’:
example.cxx:43:   instantiated from here
example.cxx:30: error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator<’
```

It seems like the compiler can't even parse this correctly, am I missing something here that makes that line completely bogus?

Comment: Imagine there was a specialization of `Foo<bool>` with a `static int funcCall = 7;`  Now parse `return Foo<B>::funcCall<5>()` -- notice how it makes no sense at the point where there is a `(`?  By default, dependent names in a C++ template refer to *identifiers*, not `template`s.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems like the compiler can't even parse this correctly, am I missing something here that makes that line completely bogus?

Yes. You need to use the `template` disambiguator:

```
return Foo<B>::template funcCall<5>();
//             ^^^^^^^^
```

This way you will tell the compiler to parse the dependent name `funcCall` as the name of a member function template, and the subsequent angular brackets as delimiters for the corresponding template arguments.

Without it, `funcCall` will be parsed as the name of a data member, while `<` and `>` will be parsed as *less-than* and *greater-than*, respectively.